# .where-query on "grandparent" in nested models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to do the follwing query, without the two models having a direct association:

```
Event.where(community_id: 1)
```

These are the three models:

```
class Community < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organizers
end

class Organizer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :community
  has_many  :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organizer
end
```

The closest I've come is to use "delegate" with the following, that works for event.communities but not for a where query:

```
delegate :community, :to => :organizer, :allow_nil => true
```

Comment: As the `events` table does not have any information about `communities`, you'll _have_ to use a JOIN, or did you mean something else?

Comment: I mean, as event.organizer.community works, I was thinking that there as well would exist ways to do a .where query on a "second generation" assocation, perhaps with the help of a :through or something similar. How could a JOIN look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Event.joins(organizer: :community).where("communities.id = ?", 1)
```

Or:

```
Event.joins(:organizer).where("organizers.community_id = ?", 1)
```